# Benefit to adding an Index for an order by column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

We have a large table (2.8M rows) where we are finding a single row by our `device_token` column

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.rpush_notifications (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    device_token character varying,
    data text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
...
```

We are constantly doing the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM rpush_notifications WHERE device_token = '...' ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'd like to add a index for our `device_token` column, and I'm wondering if there is any benefit to creating an additional index for `updated_at` or creating a multicolumn index for both columns `device_token` and `updated_at` given that we are ordering by, i.e.:

```sql
CREATE INDEX foo ON rpush_notifications(device_token, updated_at)
```

I have been unable to find an answer that would help me understand if there would be any performance benefit to adding `updated_at` to the index given the query we are running above. Any help appreciated. We are running Postgresql11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a performance benefit if you combine both columns just like you did (`(device_token, updated_at)`), because the database can easily find the entries with the specific `device_token` and it does not need to do the sorting during the query.

Even better would be an index on `(device_token, updated_at DESC)` as it gives you the requested row as the first one with this `device_token`, so there is no need to get the first and start a sequential scan from there on to find the last.

Comment: Thank you! And I had no idea you could add DESC/ASC in the index.

Comment: PostgreSQL knows how to jump to the end of the index equality bucket and then follow backwards.  Adding DESC won't hurt, but also won't help here.